# Php first split then for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, split

I have a string like this:

```
$d = 'game, story, animation, video';
```

And I want to change it to a result like this:

```
<a href="game">game</a>, <a href="story">story</a>, <a href="animation">animation</a>, <a href="video">video</a>
```

So I think I have to split $d by ',' then use a `for` loop.

I have tried this:

```
$d = 'game, story, animation, video';

list($a, $b, $c, $d) = explode(" ,", $d);
```

But how do I split it if I don't know how many ',' are going to be there, and reach the desired result?

Comment: That should give you a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways this could be accomplished here is one.
by using a `foreach` loop you should be able to accomplish what you are attempting to do.

You also need to assign you array items correctly, by casting as a string and using the `[ ]` shorthand or using `array()`

```
$d = "game, story, animation, video";
$out = '' ;

foreach(explode(",",$d) as $item){
    $out .= "<a href='$item' />$item</a>";
}

echo $out;
```

and if you need the `,` between you could use this

```
$d = "game, story, animation, video";
$out = [] ;

foreach(explode(",",$d) as $item){
    $out []= "<a href='$item' />$item</a>";
}

echo implode(",",$out);
```

read more here

[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: btw. i have $d = "game, story, animation, video";  how i am goona change this into this $d = ['game', 'story', 'animation', 'video'];

Comment: game, story, animation, video is a single sentence i guess.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to realise that you can break this line into two parts:

```
list($a, $b, $c, $d) = explode(" ,", $d);
```

First, it takes the string `$d` and splits it into an array, let's call it `$items`:

```
$items = explode(" ,", $d);
```

Then the `list()` construct takes the items from that array and puts them into separate named variables:

```
list($a, $b, $c, $d) = $items;
```

If you don't know how many items are going to be in the list, you can just skip the second step, and work with the array, probably using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    echo "Doing something with '$item'...";
}
```

Comment: Your explode separator is back to front.  Or rather, should read comma space not space comma.  Though it looks as if the OP's input format has changed through history.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$in  = 'game, story, animation, video';
$out = preg_replace('@([a-z]+)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $in);
var_dump($out);
```

Or:

```
$tags = explode(',', $in);
$tags = array_map('trim', $tags);
$out  = [];
foreach($tags as $tag)
    $out[] = '<a href="' . $tag . '">' . $tag . '</a>';

$out = implode(', ', $out);
var_dump($out);
```

Output for each:

```
string(112) "<a href="game">game</a>, <a href="story">story</a>, <a href="animation">animation</a>, <a href="video">video</a>"
```

Comment: I could have dropped the array_map('trim', $array) line (which trims white space from each element of the array) by exploding on the string: ', '.